# Help identifying perennial in bloom currently in Denver

Tags: identification, flowering, perennials

This plant just started blooming in my front yard. It has a deep green foliage as seen in the picture. It’s about a foot wide and at least 2 feet tall. It just started blooming these quarter to half-dollar sized yellow-orange flowers to look a little bit like a sunflower.

Any help identifying is greatly appreciated!

[image: yellow orange flower]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to be an easy ID to make, because there are several herbaceous perennial plants that produce daisy like flowers in yellow/orange shades in summer through to autumn, most with many varieties, and it can be difficult to tell precisely which is which. The notched petals suggest *Helenium*, but usually, the petals are flexed back, and that doesn't seem to be the case in your photo. If they are flexed, then it's more likely to be *Helenium*. *Rudbeckia* is another one, but it seems just a little early to be that, and it definitely isn't one of the *Inula* varieties.

It may be one of the perennial *Helianthus* varieties - sunflowers are the tallest and are just annuals, but there are many lower growing, perennial varieties of varying heights and spreads. The other possibility is *Heliopsis*, another perennial with flowers in similar shades and many varieties, but the appearance of the centre of the flower makes this less likely.

Comment: Would coreopsis be a possibility ?

Comment: @blacksmith37 - not with those leaves. It's most likely a helianthus, although it also resembles Heliopsis decapetalus.